# Convert Tensorflow model with multiple inputs to OpenVino IR format

Tags: python, tensorflow, intel, openvino

When trying to convert a custom model built using `tensorflow` I came across the following issue.
The model has two inputs and is currently in the `saved_model` format.
When running:

`python mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir C:/path_to/model_saved --input_shape [1,128,128,3],[1,1,1,64]`

An error is thrown

`[ ERROR ]  Please provide input layer names for input layer shapes.`

How am I supposed to provide the input names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying input shapes for several layers, you must provide names for the inputs for which shapes will be overwritten. For multiple input topology, specify the inputs as below:

```
python mo.py --saved_model_dir --input input_name_1,input_name_2 --input_shape [input_shape_1],[input_shape_2]
```

Refer to [Converting a TensorFlow Model](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html#command-line-interface-cli-examples-using-tensorflow-specific-parameters) documentation.